# SAPUI5 - Implementing smart variant management

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have implemented Smart table with TablePersonalisation & VariantManagement. I have deployed my application in ABAB repository & tested. When I save a new variant, It gets saved. But it is not retrieved.

[image: XML]

I have not coded anything for variant management in controller. Below is the screenshot of json data that is passed & saved in backend.

[image: Request Sent]

[image: This is the error in console.]

domain:8010/sap/bc/lrep/flex/data/tracking.Component not found.

Please suggest.

Comment: Where are you running the app?

In order to use the personalization services in a launchpad, there is a setting to allow this.

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew We run this app both in FLP & from ABAB repository(BSP link). Both causes same issue. How to enable flexibility service in ABAB or kindly provide the settings required to make this work.

Comment: [Here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/3ca6847da92847d79b27753d690ac5d5/Cloud/en-US/cb10beafb67c4ba09c13a3e6a9094b6d.html) you can find the docu for the Cloud Launchpad 

(SAP Cloud Platform Portal -> Portal on the Neo Environment -> SAP Fiori Launchpad Sites -> Administrator Guide -> Launchpad Settings)  [Here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/17ae0e97e0fc424a9c368f350c0ba6bd/2.10/en-US/6107ee41f89a43c9af0aa279fe039cca.html) for the ABAP Launchpad (SAP Help Portal->SAP Fiori Launchpad->Setting Up the Launchpad->Configuring the Launchpad)

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew we have configured. But no luck. Still facing the same issue. Why it is trying to get tracking.component from /sap/bc/lrep/flex/data/. Is this created automatically? or we need to do some coding.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and to resolve the issue, I had to modify the routes in the neo-app.json as below.  In my case, I have an ABAP backend system, and the way I understand it now, is that these routes can help identify where the persistance is done for the variants.  Look at:

`"path": "/sap/bc/lrep/changes",   "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/variants", "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/flex/settings", "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/flex/data"`

neo-app.json contents:

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/webapp/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/webapp/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/sap/opu/odata",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "S4H",
        "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
      },
      "description": "S4H"
    },
    {
      "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/flex/data",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "S4H",
        "entryPath": "/sap/bc/lrep/flex/data"
      },
      "description": "S4H_data"
    },
    {
      "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/flex/settings",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "S4H",
        "entryPath": "/sap/bc/lrep/flex/settings"
      },
      "description": "S4H_settings"
    }      
 ,
    {
      "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/changes",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "S4H",
        "entryPath": "/sap/bc/lrep/changes"
      },
      "description": "S4H_changes"
    }  
 ,
    {
      "path": "/sap/bc/lrep/variants",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "S4H",
        "entryPath": "/sap/bc/lrep/variants"
      },
      "description": "S4H_variants"
    }  
  ],
  "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true
}
```

Comment: Can't you combine those 4 entries into one? Like `"path": "/sap/bc/lrep/"` ? They all have the same destination 